# Setting a public variable to use class wide

Tags: apex

I have a class in apex and a few methods inside. I want to declare a variable that can be used in all methods.

```
public class Address_Penetration_ApexController {  
    public List<String> neverUnits = new List<String>();
    @AuraEnabled
    public static list getAddress_Penetration(String civicAddress,String streetName,String streetType,String city,String province) {             
        neverUnits.add("apple");
    neverUnits.add("mango");
    }   
    public static list getAddress_NeverUnits() {
        return neverUnits;
    }    
}
```

These are the error messages I get when I run the above code

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot store state in your server-side Aura or LWC controllers. All state must be stored on the client in your components' variables and passed in to your server-side controllers.

Here, `neverUnits` is declared as an instance variable, so you cannot access it from a `static` method (which doesn't have an instance associated with it). That's why you're getting a syntax error instead of unexpected runtime behavior.

Even if you did declare it `static`, however, it would not persist values across calls to the server because that's not supported in Lightning controllers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @David Reed. Would you know if this also applies to Apex Action classes that are used in flows?

Comment: @user135792 Please open a new question with that follow up (see [ask])

Comment: the question can be found here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/397031/123882.

Answer (score 1):

Add `static` to the list declaration. `public static List<String> neverUnits = new List<String>();`

This will associate the variable with the class. Static methods only have access to static variables. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm

https://csawesome.runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/csawesome/Unit5-Writing-Classes/topic-5-7-static-vars-methods.html

You also need to annotate the method `getAddress_NeverUnits` with `@AuraEnabled` like you did with the method `getAddress_Penetration` to give your component access to the method.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_AuraEnabled.htm

Comment: As said by David Reed the static variable will be reset on each invocation of an AuraEnabled method so this is not a solution.

Comment: Thank you @David. Something that I was not aware of.