# Storing state in invocableApex class - Flow Action

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I have a record-triggered flow on the Accounts object. This flow invokes an Apex Action method called `sayHello`, which takes the name of a public group as its argument:

```
public class MyClass {
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='Say Hello')
    public static void sayHello(String groupName) {
        
        List<GroupMember> newList = [SELECT Group.Id 
                                        FROM GroupMember
                                        WHERE Group.Name = groupName];
        
        HelloSettings__c match = [SELECT Group_Name
                                        FROM HelloSettings__c 
                                        WHERE Group.Name = groupName];

        List<GroupMember> oldList = [SELECT Group.Id
                                        FROM GroupMember
                                        WHERE Group.Name = match.Group_Name__c]
        
        // compare oldList to newList to see who has left 
        // since the last time `sayHello()` was called
        
        // store newList in Old_List__c picklist field
        // so that `sayHello()` can access it the next 
        // time it is called
        match.Old_List__c = newList;

    }
}
```

`sayHello()` retrieves and stores the members of `groupName` in a list called `groupUsers` and then checks to see who has left this group since the last invocation of `sayHello()`.

**Problem:** How can `sayHello` determine who has left the group since the last time it was called?

**Attempted solution:**

Store a copy of `groupUsers` somewhere, so that `sayHello()` can access it the next time it is called. I'm not sure where to store the list, though. Possible solutions:

1. ***Store the list in a class variable.***

   But I'm not sure if this value will be reset each time the flow is triggered.
2. ***Store the list in a picklist field (this is the approach shown in the code above).***

   There is a `sayHelloSettings` object that stores information about the groups that `sayHello()` is called on, so I was thinking I could save the list in a picklist field on that object.

   But is it possible to store a list of type `List<GroupMember>` in a picklist field?

   Also, picklists have a limit of 150, so not a very general solution.
3. ***Store the list in a flow variable.***

   Is it possible to create/update this variable programmatically inside `sayHello()`?

I prefer solutions (1) or (2), but I'm not sure if they're antipatterns and was wondering if there's a better solution out there.

Alternatively, is there a way to check membership history for a public group? This would be the ideal solution, as I wouldn't have to save the list.

Comment: What's the purpose of this question? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please see the [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: consecutive executions of an apex invocable method - I'd use sobjects to preserve the state - save it as JSON